# Question shows 2 close votes even though the community voted to leave it open

Tags: bug

I recently reviewed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43690875/python-list-updating-elements-when-appending). Both votes are because

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

I don't agree that this applies (the OP shows what he tried and asks a specific question about it) and I don't think that the question deserves to be closed, and the majority [voted](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/15982884) to leave it open (3 for leaving it open, evidently 2 for closing).

The system shows the review being completed:
[image]

However, it still shows 2 close votes:
[image]

Why are they still listed given that the majority voted against closing?

Comment: Relevant: [How do Close votes Expire?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97556/close-votes-expire-too-soon-for-low-traffic-tags), [What happens when reviewer hits "Leave Open" button?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139834/what-exactly-happens-with-the-button-leave-open-previously-do-not-close), [Why do close votes have priority?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280818/why-do-close-votes-have-priority/280819#280819)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That the review queue decided to leave it open doesn't mean that the close votes get deleted, it just means that the review queue decided to leave it open.

The only effect that it has on the votes is that, if it hadn't already started from the question getting enough views, the timer for the aging of those close votes will start.